# Emacs Wanderlust error: "no such file or directory, gnutls-cli"

Tags: emacs

I am trying to open gmail with Emacs. `M-x wl` yields the following error message.

```
/usr/bin/mail is not an executable.  Setting mail-interactive to t.
Initializing...
Loading mail-mime-setup...done
gnus-mime-setup is not found.
emh-setup is not found.
Updating addresses...done
Checking environment...
Auto plugged off at imap.gmail.com:993
byte-code: Searching for program: no such file or directory, gnutls-cli
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It wants you to install a utility called `gnutls-cli`.  If you're on a Debian-derived distribution, `apt-get install gnutls-bin` which contains this utility and a few others.  If you're on something else, please edit your question to include more details.

Comment: At least in squeeze, the package is called [gnutls-bin](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/gnutls-bin).